# SQL Server 2012: Select literal and compare to the literal in Where

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, literals

So, basically, in my query, I want to have a statuses column that will contain 1 or more statuses based on certain criteria. A user should be able to filter/search also on those status messages in that column. I'm not sure on the syntax to make this happen.

This selects 0 to 2 status divs in my column, which I display as is.

Here's theoretically what I want to happen:

```
Select fields, (select CASE WHEN root_directory IS NULL THEN '<div class="gray status">Unbuilt</div>' ELSE '' END + ' ' + (select top(1) CASE WHEN isnull(payment_received,0) = 1 THEN '' ELSE '<div class="red status">Unpaid</div>' END
FROM invoice C
WHERE C.id = B.id) as statuses
FROM table
WHERE statuses LIKE '%Unbuilt%'
```

Thoughts on how to WHERE LIKE my statuses column?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `WHERE` clause cannot refer to columns in the select list.  Logically speaking, the `WHERE` is applied before anything is selected.

You can, however, filter on the criteria by which you are setting the `statuses` result column.  As a bonus, you will then be able to get rid of one of the `CASE` expressions in the select list, since the `WHERE` clause will fix which erstwhile case applies.

It's unclear to which table alias `B` in your original table applies, but `table` is the only real candidate.  Supposing that `B` refers to table `table`, then, something along these lines will do what you appear to want:

```
Select B.fields, '<div class="gray status">Unbuilt</div> '
  + CASE C.payment_received
     WHEN 1 THEN ''
     ELSE '<div class="red status">Unpaid</div>'
    END
FROM
  table B
  JOIN invoice C ON C.id = B.id
WHERE root_directory IS NULL
```